# python, cron and the interaction with Growl

Tags: macos, python, cron, growl

I have the following python file called temp.py

```
import subprocess
   p = subprocess.Popen('growlnotify -m \"Program is not running\"', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT) 
   retval = p.wait()
   print "end"
```

it works fine from the command line with 'python temp.py' and `sudo python temp.py'  (all it needs to do is display the growl notification)

I open up crontab with 'crontab -e' (i'm on OSX if that helps. 
I add the line

- 8-23 * * * python /Users/xxx/Dropbox/scripts/temp.py >>   /Users/xx/running.txt

I expect the program to execute every minute from 8am to 23pm - and it does, the 'running.txt' file is filling up - but I'm not getting the growl notifications - any ideas?

Comment: It might not be possible to execute growlnotify from there because growl is dependent on the graphical environment (and more?). Check your log files for errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default path in crontab is `/usr/bin:/bin`. If you installed growlnotify somewhere else like `/usr/local/bin/`, you have to specify the full path in the script.

Comment: Yep - although it was the combination of this answer and the comment that got me there.